# I want to port my delicious bookmarks to my website

Tags: bookmarks, delicious-api

I started building a app that will automatically download my delicious bookmarks, and save to a database, so they I can view them on my own website in my favoured format.

I am forced to use oAuth, as I have a yahoo id to login to delicious. The problem is I am stuck at the point where oAuth requires a user to manually go and authenticate.

Is there a code/ guidelines available anywhere I can follow? All I want is a way to automatically save my bookmarks to my database.

Any help is appreciated. I can work on java, .net and php. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Delicious Provides an API for this already:

### [https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/all?](http://delicious.com/help/api#posts_all)

Returns all posts. Please use sparingly. Call the update function to see if you need to fetch this at all.

#### Arguments

- &tag={TAG}

  - (optional) Filter by this tag.
- &start={#}

  - (optional) Start returning posts this many results into the set.
- &results={#}

  - (optional) Return this many results.
- &fromdt={CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ}

  - (optional) Filter for posts on this date or later
- &todt={CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ}

  - (optional) Filter for posts on this date or earlier
- &meta=yes

  - (optional) Include change detection signatures on each item in a 'meta' attribute. Clients wishing to maintain a synchronized local store of bookmarks should retain the value of this attribute - its value will change when any significant field of the bookmark changes.

Example

```
$ curl https://user:passwd@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/all

<posts tag="" user="user">
  <post href="http://www.weather.com/" description="weather.com"
  hash="6cfedbe75f413c56b6ce79e6fa102aba" tag="weather reference"
  time="2005-11-29T20:30:47Z" />
    ...
  <post href="http://www.nytimes.com/"
  description="The New York Times - Breaking News, World News & Multimedia"
  extended="requires login" hash="ca1e6357399774951eed4628d69eb84b"
  tag="news media" time="2005-11-29T20:30:05Z" />
</posts>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are also public and private RSS feeds for bookmarks, so if you can read and parse XML you don't necessarily need to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

Note however that if you registered with Delicious after December, and therefore use your Yahoo account, the above will not work and you'll need to use OAuth.

There are a number of full examples on the Delicious support site, see for example: http://support.delicious.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=3698